# How to get rid of this white block at the right of my view-div?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi im doing a landing page with a scroll of two views and I get this white block at the right:

[image]

This is the html fragment of the divs I created

[image]

This is the current fragment of the css of the slides

[image]

I have make all sorts of changes in padding and margin but it doesnt work, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css file:

```
* {
    background: #000 !important;
    color: #0f0 !important;
    outline: solid #f00 1px !important;
}
```

Adding this will help you find the rogue element that's creating the white space.